# Unable to completely uninstall/remove Sublime text from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sublime-text

I had installed Sublime_text-3 in my system (Ubuntu 16.04). I want to uninstall it and i followed the link http://www.ubuntoid.com/install-sublime-text-2-3-ubuntu-16-04/

and i typed in the terminal as:

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sublime-text-installer`

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`

But in the terminal now if i give `locate sublime_text` then it shows the following folders

`Dilip@Dilip:~$ locate sublime_text
/home/Dilip/.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
/home/Dilip/.local/share/icons/sublime_text.png
/opt/sublime_text
/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop`

I have deleted all the sublime_text files/folders (sudo rm) from all those folders where it belonged.

Now again if i give the command `locate sublime_text` again, i get the same context in the terminal

`Dilip@Dilip:~$ locate sublime_text
/home/Dilip/.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
/home/Dilip/.local/share/icons/sublime_text.png
/opt/sublime_text
/usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop`.

How is this possible? Even after removing i am getting these. I even went to the specific folders and if i check there are no any sublime_text related files.

Why is this happening? How can i resolve this issue?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a bug most probably. You can use the following commands or method to verify your operation.

1. Commands

If you use one of the two commands but find out nothing, it proves that you have removed it.

ls sublime*

or

sudo find / -name sublime*

2. Search the keyword 'sublime' in the directories you listed. If all of them are not existed, it proves that you have already removed them all.

Afterwards, you can try to install Sublime again. If the new sublime works well, it is a new proof.